Rviz qxcbconnection could not connect to display
When I launched roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch from the  workstation I got the error qxcbconnection could not connect to display. Then I login to the Turtlebot pc from the workstation using the command ssh turtlebot@ - X. This time rviz was launched but the Turtlebot did not move on the Rviz environment. Although Rviz was open there were some messages on the terminal
libGL error: failed to authenticate magic 2
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

How can I solve the issue?
